# Error with compiling and source code(AOSPA)

Tags: android, compiler-errors

When I compiling the AOSPA ROM, it always stopped with following massage:
make: *** No rule to make target 'out/target/product/nx529j/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libqdutils_intermediates/export_includes', needed by 'out/target/product/nx529j/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libsurfaceflinger_intermediates/import_includes'. Stop.
I have tried to find solution on Google, github and XDA-Developers forum, but I can't found any solutions .
Wha shoi I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Simple but no perfect:

```
$ pushd out/target/product/nx529j/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/
$ mkdir libqdutils_intermediates
$ touch libqdutils_intermediates/export_includes
$ popd
```

Do not clear cache or delete the `out/` folder, just try to build （`bruch`/`make`/`launch`） again .

---

The reason for this error is missing `libqdutils.so` , the one you can pull from device. The solution above just for showing up the missing `libqdutils.so` error for you in next build you try.

---

Once you encounter missing `libqdutils.so` error, just (be sure android device connected to pc for `adb`):

```
$ pushd ./vendor/{manufacturer}/{device}/proprietary/
$ adb pull /system/lib/libqdutils.so ./
$ popd
```

Reference:

1. https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2357126
2. https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2754997&page=147